# How to Boot up the Rasberry Pi for the first time?

Tags: boot

So, I am very new to using a rasberry pi, and I am trying to get it to boot up for the first time.  I just used a formatted MicroCD Card, complete with NOOBS, and I am using an HDMI cable with a TV to get it set  up. 
However, the TV is just saying that it there is no signal to receive from anything.
The ACT (green) light is going solid for about a second and then blinking twice and going out.  And the Power (red) light is solid for the entire time that I am trying to get it to boot up.
Is there a step that I am missing, or is there something I have to do to get it set up to run on a TV?

Comment: Read [this helpful documentation](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) ... *2 flashes: The SD Card cannot be read*

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Jaromanda X, and from [elinux.org](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern):

> Green LED blinks in a specific pattern: 
>   ...
>       2 flashes: The SD Card cannot be read.
>       Solution : Format card and flash Raspbian with Pi Installer from Terminal.
>
> - SD Formatter (Mac + Win) https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_mac/index.html
> - Pi SD Installer by RayViljoen: https://github.com/RayViljoen/Raspberry-PI-SD-Installer-OS-X